# What drivers should I install to use the trackpad "two finger swipe" on Windows 7 running under VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, trackpad, virtualization, driver, virtualbox

I'm using Oracle VirtualBox to run several VMs on my MacBook and am unable to use the trackpad to "two finger swipe" to the previous webpage under Win 7.

I'm guessing this is a driver issue.

Since my mac never came with a CD, or anything else, where can I download the Win7 drivers that will allow me to properly "swipe" under Win7?

(The OracleBox drivers do currently support two finger scroll, but not the "go back" macro in IE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-touch gestures aren't built in to Windows. you'll need to use third party utilities to get these sort of functions. Check out [this page](http://lifehacker.com/5807358/how-to-get-mac-os-xs-best-features-on-windows) for instructions on how to get the various mac functions working in Win7.

Comment: The link to Life Hacker doesn't seem to work any more, it redirects me to: http://jalopnik.com/392143/2008-alfa-romeo-brera-s-bred-specifically-for-english-dragons

Answer (score 1):

Those gestures are specific features of the Mac operating system, so they are not supported on Windows by default.

[Elan Smart Pad](http://www.emc.com.tw/eng/tpn_sp_fun.asp) is software which will allow you to do thinks linke gestures on a trackpad, so maybe there is your solution?